# Substituir maker A e B do google maps no exemplo "Place autocomplete and directions"

Tags: javascript, google, maps, marker

Estou estudando a api do google maps, e estou tentando personalizar este exemplo do proprio google, porem já li a documentaçao sobre marker do google porem sem sucesso ao tentar substituir os marcadores "A" e "B" deste exemplo. Como posso substituir os dois marcadores "A" e "B" deste exemplo do google maps com javascript? Desde já agradeço.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Place Autocomplete and Directions</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
      /* Always set the map height explicitly to define the size of the div
       * element that contains the map. */
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
      /* Optional: Makes the sample page fill the window. */
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      .controls {
        margin-top: 10px;
        border: 1px solid transparent;
        border-radius: 2px 0 0 2px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        height: 32px;
        outline: none;
        box-shadow: 0 2px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
      }

      #origin-input,
      #destination-input {
        background-color: #fff;
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 15px;
        font-weight: 300;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 0 11px 0 13px;
        text-overflow: ellipsis;
        width: 200px;
      }

      #origin-input:focus,
      #destination-input:focus {
        border-color: #4d90fe;
      }

      #mode-selector {
        color: #fff;
        background-color: #4d90fe;
        margin-left: 12px;
        padding: 5px 11px 0px 11px;
      }

      #mode-selector label {
        font-family: Roboto;
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: 300;
      }

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div style="display: none">
        <input id="origin-input" class="controls" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter an origin location">

        <input id="destination-input" class="controls" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a destination location">

        <div id="mode-selector" class="controls">
          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-walking" checked="checked">
          <label for="changemode-walking">Walking</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-transit">
          <label for="changemode-transit">Transit</label>

          <input type="radio" name="type" id="changemode-driving">
          <label for="changemode-driving">Driving</label>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="map"></div>

    <script>
// This example requires the Places library. Include the libraries=places
// parameter when you first load the API. For example:
// <script
// src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places">

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    mapTypeControl: false,
    center: {lat: -33.8688, lng: 151.2195},
    zoom: 13
  });

  new AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map);
}

/**
 * @constructor
 */
function AutocompleteDirectionsHandler(map) {
  this.map = map;
  this.originPlaceId = null;
  this.destinationPlaceId = null;
  this.travelMode = 'WALKING';
  this.directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
  this.directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
  this.directionsDisplay.setMap(map);

  var originInput = document.getElementById('origin-input');
  var destinationInput = document.getElementById('destination-input');
  var modeSelector = document.getElementById('mode-selector');

  var originAutocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(originInput);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  originAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  var destinationAutocomplete =
      new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(destinationInput);
  // Specify just the place data fields that you need.
  destinationAutocomplete.setFields(['place_id']);

  this.setupClickListener('changemode-walking', 'WALKING');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-transit', 'TRANSIT');
  this.setupClickListener('changemode-driving', 'DRIVING');

  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(originAutocomplete, 'ORIG');
  this.setupPlaceChangedListener(destinationAutocomplete, 'DEST');

  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(originInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(
      destinationInput);
  this.map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(modeSelector);
}

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupClickListener = function(
    id, mode) {
  var radioButton = document.getElementById(id);
  var me = this;

  radioButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    me.travelMode = mode;
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.setupPlaceChangedListener = function(
    autocomplete, mode) {
  var me = this;
  autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', this.map);

  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    if (!place.place_id) {
      window.alert('Please select an option from the dropdown list.');
      return;
    }
    if (mode === 'ORIG') {
      me.originPlaceId = place.place_id;
    } else {
      me.destinationPlaceId = place.place_id;
    }
    me.route();
  });
};

AutocompleteDirectionsHandler.prototype.route = function() {
  if (!this.originPlaceId || !this.destinationPlaceId) {
    return;
  }
  var me = this;

  this.directionsService.route(
      {
        origin: {'placeId': this.originPlaceId},
        destination: {'placeId': this.destinationPlaceId},
        travelMode: this.travelMode
      },
      function(response, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          me.directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      });
};

    </script>
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[Link do exemplo funcionando](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-directions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A **API do Google Maps** é bastante **rica e complexa**, então eu sugiro que você saiba bastante `javascript` e ame ler documentação. Com isto sugiro arduamente que **"comece pelo início"**, qual o [link é este](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial). **Vamos a resposta da sua pergunta...**

Imaginando que você tenha um **nível intermediário/avançado** em `javascript` e na **API do Google Maps**, irei fornecer um **código básico** para o entendimento de como **"CRIAR MARCADORES"**.

Não á mistério em se criar um marcador (marker) simples, eles dependem apenas da **LAT(LATITUDE) e LNG(LONGITUDE)**.

**O que é Latitude?**

> Latitude é o ângulo entre o plano do equador à superfície de referência. A latitude mede-se para norte e para sul do equador, entre 90º sul, no Pólo Sul e 90º norte, no Pólo Norte.

**O que é longitude?**

> Longitude, algumas vezes representada pela letra grega λ (lambda), descreve a localização de um lugar na Terra medido em graus, de zero a 180 para leste ou para oeste, a partir do Meridiano de Greenwich.

**Como consigo as mesmas, através da API?**

> Como eu disse, você precisa ler atentamente desde o ínicio da documentação, pois neste seu caso é necessário diversos conhecimentos de diversos "setores" diferentes de dentro da API do Google Maps, mas um dos modos de como conseguir está neste link [(Place Autocomplete)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete).

Agora, dando exemplo em algoritmo...

Utilizarei **duas(2) coordenadas** para **dois(2) locais diferentes**, que as mesmas foram retiradas [deste link](https://www.latlong.net/) para fins de **prototipagem rápida do algoritmo abaixo**:

**Local (1) - BAIRRO TIJUCA, RIO DE JANEIRO:**

```
var myLatLngTijuca = {lat: -20.514690, lng: -54.664059};
```

**Local (2) - BAIRRO BARRA, RIO DE JANEIRO:**

```
var myLatLngBarra = {lat: -22.996309, lng: -43.400200};
```

Agora que já possuímos as duas coordenadas para os dois locais, você deve criar **dois(2) marker simples** para serem exibidos nas mesmas, e **como fazer isto?** Precisamos criar um novo objeto do tipo `Marker` e adicionar algumas propriedades a este objeto, você pode ler mais sobre isto [neste link](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple).

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: AQUI VOCÊ DEVE INSERIR O OBJETO COM A LAT E LNG,
    map: AQUI VOCÊ DEVE INSERIR O OBJETO DO MAPA,
    title: AQUI VOCÊ DEVE INSERIR UM TÍTULO PARA O MARKER'
});
```

Agora, para finalizar o nosso código básico de prototipagem, iremos desenvolver de uma forma geral o mesmo:

```
  function initMap() {
    var myLatLng = {lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
    var myLatLngTijuca = {lat: -20.514690, lng: -54.664059};
    var myLatLngBarra = {lat: -22.996309, lng: -43.400200};

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 4,
      center: myLatLng
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLngTijuca ,
      map: map,
      title: 'TIJUCA!'
    });

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatLngBarra ,
      map: map,
      title: 'BARRA!'
    });
  }
```

Comment: Entendi e muito boa a explicação! Consegui executar o seu exemplo com sucesso. Porém a questão e colocar isto dentro do codigo do exemplo "Place autocomplete and Directions" do google maps substituindo os marcadores "A" e "B" que aparecem no mapa. Colocar marcadores no mapa eu consigo de acordo o seu exemplo, mais não consigo subistituir os marcadores "A" e "B" do exemplo "Place autocomplete and Directions" (Do codigo da questão).

Comment: @cristy então, foi como eu disse, infelizmente esta Api è complexa, e você terá que aprendê-la toda.. Porque  a “Place AutoComplete..” è uma junção de diversas outras técnicas do google maps, como por exemplo os “bounds”, aí você teria que saber o que è isto também entre outras dezenas de coisas, compreende?

Comment: Compreendo. Vou continuar lendo a documentação.

Comment: @cristy inicie pelo link que deixei na resposta, vai fazendo devagar e testando cada função e propriedade para você ver como funciona.. Existe uma área da documentação que informa o que cada objeto, classe faz também.